# How to draw edges on a sphere to make parts that fit into each other

Tags: bezier-curves, edges, 3d-printing

I am trying to make sphere shaped designs with moving parts like spaceship doors & windows for 3d printing. However, the doors/windows don't always follow the edges on the UV sphere.

Is there a way to "draw" edges on the surface of the sphere that I can use to cut certain shapes out of it? The best example I can think of are the classic flying saucer spaceships with the lowering door in older movies.

Below are my two objects: the sphere (orange) & the shape I want to trace about the surface of the sphere to eventually cut them into two separate meshes that can fit into each other.

NOTE : I have tried using the knife projection approach and the shape does not follow the curve of the sphere. (2nd image). The third animation is the closest example I can think of for my goal.
[image]

[image]

[image: example objective]
<sub>(source: [gbtcdn.com](https://des.gbtcdn.com/uploads/pdm-desc-pic/Electronic/image/2016/09/07/1473209704840825.gif))</sub>

Comment: you can cut edges with the knife tool or with the knife project tool, maybe check these tools and tell if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: I've used the knife tool, but I was looking for a way to draw a shape and then overlay it on the surface of the sphere. The knife tool doesn't give the clean curves I'm looking for.

Comment: the knife project tool is probably more convenient as you can prepare the shape before, see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bR-hWPirFZQ , but maybe show some pictures of your project?

Comment: also it all depends on the topology of your object, you can delete some faces and scale down the edge to create your doors, having a clean topology will make the modeling easy

Comment: wow that link helped a lot! I'm going to test it out, as I need it to wrap around the different sides of the sphere.

Comment: @moonboots that didn't quite do it, as it's not following the full curvature of the sphere's surface.

Comment: please show a drawing of what you're trying to achieve, it will help to find a solution. Also, try to work with as few polygons as possible, your object is high-poly and it won't help to easily work on it

Comment: @moonboots this is the example I'm thinking of: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fequatoriallazybunny&psig=AOvVaw2WGzfNM96Y_B6Lt-WcGnOA&ust=1612323549605000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPCktLWjyu4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ

Answer (score 2):

You work with too many polygons and you should think another way. If we try something like your last picture:

- Create a UV sphere, stretch it on the Z axis, keep only 1/32 that you mirror on the X and Z axis:

[image]

- Cut the hole with a knife:

[image]

- Extrude inwards:

[image]

- Use an *Array* in *Object Offset* mode to make the mesh rotate around an empty, work on the mesh as long as necessary before applying the *Mirror* and *Array* modifiers:

[image]

Comment: this helped, but I am really looking to put organic shapes and circles on the surface. That's why the original image had the curves. Drawing the circles on the surface isn't coming out even.